# Incorrectly mounted docker volume that cannot be removed

Tags: docker

I tried to mount a volume using docker run, but I put the wrong folder. This is the command I did:

```
docker run --name my-apache -p 80:80 -d -v ~/home/myusername/html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

Notice the `~` before `/home/myusername`... I should not have put `~` there because it created a `/home/myusername/home/myusername/...` folder

I've tried to remove the volume with:
`docker rm -f -v my-apache` but with no avail. I don't have sudo on this machine. Am I just doomed to having another home folder that is impossible to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat and take advantage of container processes running as root to get root access.

Mount `~` as a volume inside a plain container like alpine. Any basic container with `rm` such as alpine, debian, or fedora will do. Commands run as root by default; an `rm -rf` inside the container be able to delete anything.

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~:/home alpine rm -rf /home/home
```

Be careful running `rm -rf` as root! Normally there's no danger since it can only delete things inside the container. But if you mount a directory from the host then anything inside the directory is fair game.